# How to build phonegap offline from command line

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using phonegap 100% from the command line. If I build while connected to the internet it works

```
$ phonegap build android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova build android'
```

But if I disconnect from the internet I get errors

```
$ phonegap build android
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build android'...
cp: no such file or directory: /Users/gregg/src/hft-mobile-app/icon.png


Running command: /Users/gregg/src/hft-mobile-app/platforms/android/cordova/build 

ANDROID_HOME=/Users/gregg/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home

Running: /Users/gregg/src/hft-mobile-app/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/gregg/src/hft-mobile-app/platforms/android/build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true



FAILURE: 
Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.


> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.

     Required by:

         :android:unspecified


> 
Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.


> 
Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.


> 
Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.

               > 
repo1.maven.org: nodename nor servname provided, or not known



* Try:

Run with 
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with 
--info
 or --debug
 option to get more log output.



BUILD FAILED




Total time: 30.753 secs


/Users/gregg/src/hft-mobile-app/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /Users/gregg/src/hft-mobile-app/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/gregg/src/hft-mobile-app/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /Users/gregg/src/hft-mobile-app/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

Error: /Users/gregg/src/hft-mobile-app/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Why is the command line version phoning home? How do I get this to build 100% offline?

Note: I see this error as the 2nd line when trying to build offline

```
cp: no such file or directory: /Users/gregg/src/hft-mobile-app/icon.png
```

But as you can see that error does not occur online. Plus supposedly whatever [that issue was was fixed according to this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli/issues/365)

I'm on OSX, I've got the Android SDK installed. I had no idea it was calling home. How do I get it to build offline?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have experienced till now. Ionic uses gradle for android build. It first time downloads all the dependencies from internet. So internet is most for first gradle build but it caches them and no internet is needed for further build.Since you are having problem why don't you globally update your cordova and ionic.

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```